# Mantis - datetimepicker

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker, mantis

I've posted this question on Mantis forum but no one has answered to me so I've decided to ask the same question here.
I've been asked for my training to make some development into the bug tracker Mantis. One of them is about preventing the user from choosing a date after the today date.
If it seems simple, none of the solutions I've found have been working for me.
Here is the input provided by default by Mantis :

```
<input tabindex="16" type="text" name="date_intervention" id="mydatetime" class="datetimepicker input-sm" data-picker-locale="fr-ca" data-picker-format="YYYY-MM-DD" size="16" data-date-end-date="0d" maxlength="20" value="2017-10-18">
```

This version of Mantis is using the 3.3.6 Bootstrap version.
Here are the solutions I've tried without success:

### Using the maxDate attribute through Javascript

```
$(function() {$( "#mydatetime" ).datetimepicker({ maxDate: new Date });});
```

### Using the data-date-start-date and data-date-end-date attributes directly into my inputs

data-date-start-date="0d"
data-date-end-date="0d"

### Using the endDate attribute through Javascript

```
$(function() { $( "#mydatetime" ).datetimepicker({ endDate: +0d });});
```

I've found those solutions into this forum but it didn't work for me.
Is there anyone who could help me please ? 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: You're initing you picker with Id, though I don't see it on your code, shouldn't be `$(".datepicker").datepicker({maxDate: '0'});` or `datetimepicker` as that is your class "identifier", other thing in your question is about DateTimePicker but your plugin seems to be just DatePicker ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I've not been clear enough concerning my examples but I've tried with the good ids in my code. I will edit this for no further confusion. Concerning your second remark I have to admit that I didn't realize there were two diferent plugins. It seems that bootstrap is using 'datetimepicker' so the plugin must be datetimepicker and not datepicker right ?

Comment: This is something you need to check out on either your code or using the browser inspecting tools and see the code which is referencing see if give you a name of the picker or either maybe a link to the page.

Comment: I've verified and it seems that it is the Boostrap datetimpicker that is used in Mantis. Now I don't understand why the solutions that supposed to work don't with me...

Comment: can you link where does mantis provided that solution so I can check it out?

Comment: Sorry for the delay answer. I've deducted its Bootstrap's cause if you use datepicker it creates another calendar and here the detailed info about it : https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Ok I see your problem now, you're using wrong option I'll write the solution for you

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you're using wrongly the option for eonasdan, for this you must use [`maxDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#maxdate) either with `new Date()`, as you were doing, or using [moment](http://momentjs.com/) (which should be included for the plugin o work)

So for your example will be this:

```
$("#mydatetime").datetimepicker({
  maxDate: moment().endOf('day') //This will set max day to choose today
});
```

And for a live example:

```js
$('#myDatepicker').datetimepicker({
 maxDate: moment().endOf('day')
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/25c11d79/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>



<br/> <!--Space for the fiddle-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to pick a time just setup your preferred [`format`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) without hour like:

```
format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
```

Comment: Thank for your detailed answer but unfortunately it's still not working... Nothing happens, I still can select future days.

Comment: Could it be it's throwing some error on your console? And Could you give me some kind of full example (preferably a link) in which I can see that example of the picker?

Comment: There's nothing in the console. For the full example I don't know how to do it. Is there some tool I can use ? Like you did with the code snippet ?

Comment: You can use [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) set up, your html, Js here an example DatePicker already set up https://jsfiddle.net/William_/20oywuno/

Comment: Thanks for your return . I've put some of my code other here :https://jsfiddle.net/5zfb6qr9/ I don't know if it can help, it couldn't even display the calendar.

Comment: Julie what you must do is wrap your input with a <div class='col-sm-6'> or a (bigger size if you want) here a working code, https://jsfiddle.net/William_/Lupg8ab5/1/ with your locale, try to impleneting and tell me if works

Answer (score -1):

Finally one of my colleague has found the solution, so I share it with you here:

```
var today= new Date(); 
$('#myDateTime').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(today);
```

Here's the site where we found the solution: 
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Thanks again William for your time.